# Typescript/React front end + Python backend web service

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, frontend

If i have a simple python backend web service (microservice) using django or flask. It takes a request (POST or GET) in the form of JSON that will include 2 integer inputs: A, and B, it'll then perform A+B and return the result as an integer in a JSON HTTP response.

And I plan to write a singe page web application using Typescript and React to access that service (send requests and getting the sum as responses) and display the results on my page. The SPA wll just have 2 text boxes for me to enter the 2 numbers, and it'll display the sum below as returned by the service when whenever I click 'submit'.

What do I need as far as my frontend is concerned (assuming backend is already running on the web).

Based on my understanding I need:

1) NPM (to install react)

2) Node.js (to use NPM)

3) React framework (installed using NPM. Yes such a simple app probably won't need it but I'm just using this as an example for a true non-trivial frontend app later on.)

4) Webpack (Same as react: I may not need this for this simple application, but in general why do I need it?)

5) Babel (only if I need to make my typescript compatible with older browsers?)

6) Bootstrap (only if I want the SPA's look and feel to be standardized and fancy?)

7) A modern browser like Chrome to display the SPA in.

What else am I missing in terms of a modern frontend tech stack for this app? IN particular, I'm curious as to the role Node.js will play here: it seems I only need node.js to use npm. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using create-react-app, all you have to do is run 'npx create-react-app app-name' in a terminal and it will set up a react project, rename all .jsx files to .tsx and run 'npm start'
It supports typescript automatically and will generate a config file for it when it detects you're using typescript.
It hides the webpack configuration and supports most common use cases out of the box.

Comment: But why do I need to run a node.js server to do frontend react development on my local machine? In production, my backend server is not even in node.js

Comment: That's just for ease of development, it allows hot reloading etc. npm run build will create a production bundle you can host anywhere (it's just html, css and js files)
You can setup all xhr request to be proxied to whatever url you want (like your python server) in package.json during development.